# Disallow Function Constructor (no-new-func) - react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, eslint

Okey, so i'm getting this Json from an api, this json have many keys of basic types but some of those keys are javascript. But javascript can't be sent through json.

So they sent me

```
   const json = keynamePlain = { arguments, body}
```

So it was a matter of just doing the insertion of a new function

```
map(json, field => {
                let a = { keyname:new Function (field.keynameplain.arguments, field.keynameplain.body) }
```

but eslint trows me this error "no-new-func" which leads to this [documentation][1]

but i dont see a way of converting this function the way they show in the documentation

```
var x = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

This is because the implementation of argument and body has to be the like the following

```
argument => {body}
```

There is any way of doing this ?
[1]: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new-func

Comment: you could always allow function constructor, since the docs say not to use that rule *where you really need to use the Function constructor* - and ... you do

Comment: Alternatively keep the rule enabled and add a `// eslint-disable-next-line no-new-func` with a comment as to the reason for override. This way it is clear it was intentional for any devs working on the code later.

Comment: @DrewReese - I didn't realise you could disable rules per-line like that - always good to learn something!

Comment: There is any way of refractoring this and avoid having this rule popup?